# C# Windows Universal: Unable to add items to DataGrid dynamically

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid, windows-10-universal

I have a few `TextBox`es, a `Button` and a `controls:DataGrid` item in my `MainPage.xaml`. When I click the button, I want the `DataGrid` to update, but it does not work for some unknown reasons.

Here's the relevant parts of the `MainPage.xaml`

```
<Button x:Name="calculateButton" Content="Calculate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="calculate_click"/>
<!--Necessary TextBoxes above the Button-->
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid">
</controls:DataGrid>
```

Here are the relevant portions of `MainPage.xaml.cs` file:

```
namespace New_Salary_Calculator
{
    public class TableData
    {
        public Double Basic { get; set; }
        public Double Fbp { get; set; }
        public Double Inh { get; set; }
        public Double Ars { get; set; }
        public Double Cur { get; set; }

        public TableData(Double basic, Double fbp, Double inh, Double ars, Double cur)
        {
            this.Basic = basic;
            this.Fbp = fbp;
            this.Inh = inh;
            this.Ars = ars;
            this.Cur = cur;
        }
    }

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public List<TableData> Data;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Data = new List<TableData>();
        }

        private void calculate_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int years = Convert.ToInt32(yearInput.Text) - 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= years; ++i)
            {
                Double pow = Math.Pow(1.09, years);
                Double basic = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(basicInput.Text) * pow),
                    fbp = Math.Round(basic * Convert.ToDouble(fbpInput.Text) / 100),
                    pf = Math.Round(basic * Convert.ToDouble(pfInput.Text) / 100),
                    grat = Math.Round(basic * Convert.ToDouble(gratInput.Text) / 100);

                Double inh = Math.Floor(basic + fbp), ars = Math.Round(fbp + basic + pf + grat);

                Double rent = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(rentInput.Text) * 12),
                    food = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(foodInput.Text) * pow),
                    investments = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(investmentsInput.Text) * pow),
                    ins = 100000;

                Double cur = inh - rent - food - investments - ins;
                Data.Add(new TableData(basic, fbp, inh, ars, cur));
            }
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = Data;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the last line of the for loop of the `calculate_click()`, I'm adding items everytime loop runs into the `List<TableData>` object `Data`. At the end of the function, I'm assigning `dataGrid.ItemsSource` as this list. But all it does is add the headers to the `DataGrid` and not the actual items inside it:

Before Clicking:
[image: Before]

After Clicking:
[image: After]

Answer (score 2):

`List<>` doesn't update data automatically or dynamically.

Use `ObservableCollection<>` instead to update your `DataGrid` realtime.

Read these documentations for further assist-

[Binding to a collection of items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart#binding-to-a-collection-of-items)

[ObservableCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Your code should look like this -

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private ObservableCollection<TableData> Data;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Data = new ObservableCollection<TableData>();
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = Data;
        }

        private void calculate_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int years = Convert.ToInt32(yearInput.Text) - 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= years; ++i)
            {
                double pow = Math.Pow(1.09, years);
                double basic = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(basicInput.Text) * pow),
                    fbp = Math.Round(basic * Convert.ToDouble(fbpInput.Text) / 100),
                    pf = Math.Round(basic * Convert.ToDouble(pfInput.Text) / 100),
                    grat = Math.Round(basic * Convert.ToDouble(gratInput.Text) / 100);

                double inh = Math.Floor(basic + fbp), ars = Math.Round(fbp + basic + pf + grat);

                double rent = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(rentInput.Text) * 12),
                    food = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(foodInput.Text) * pow),
                    investments = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(investmentsInput.Text) * pow),
                    ins = 100000;

                Double cur = inh - rent - food - investments - ins;
                Data.Add(new TableData(basic, fbp, inh, ars, cur));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So given the above `.cs` code, just changing the `List<>` to `ObservableCollection<>` should automatically update the `DataGrid`?

Comment: Yes, sure. You have to add the namespace. (That's not a big deal at all!)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Still the same thing as in question. Only the headers getting added, not the `ObservableCollection` items

Comment: @Sparker0i Hi! I have edited my answer and added a code example. Please have a look.

Comment: Hi, now the headers appear even before the click, but the Data still does not show up in the DataGrid

Comment: @Sparker0i See my above reply.

Answer (score 1):

> now the headers appear even before the click, but the Data still does not show up in the DataGrid

Actually, Mahmudul Hasan's reply has explained all things related to your question. I also tested his code, it did work for me.

If you still could not update data on DataGrid when click the 'Calculate' button, there might be some other issues in your own code.

According to your screenshot, I made a simple XAML page like the following:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="yearInput"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="basicInput"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="fbpInput"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="pfInput"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="gratInput"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="rentInput"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="foodInput"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="investmentsInput"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>

    <Button x:Name="calculateButton" Content="Calculate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="calculate_click" />
    <!--Necessary TextBoxes above the Button-->
    <controls:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid">
    </controls:DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

And the c# code is the same with Mahmudul Hasan. Please create a new blank UWP project and copy these code to test. I believe it will work.

[image]

To use the DataGrid, you also need to install the correct nuget package. Please see the [How to: Add a DataGrid control to a page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics) to check if you have installed it correctly.

You even could get the official code sample form [GitHub](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/DataGrid).

After that, if you now can update the data on DataGrid successfully. Then, the next step is to understand why you need to use `ObservableCollection` class. You need to read the documents in Mahmudul Hasan's reply carefully. It has explained all relevant things.

After you understand all the above information, if you're a beginner to UWP, I could give you some suggestions on developping UWP app. Like you're using DataGrid control, the DataGrid control is included in [Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/). The WindowsCommunityToolkit is open source on [GitHub](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit). When you're facing an issue in using this controls, you could check its document to see if you're doing the correct things in using this control. You even could download the whole WindowsCommunityToolkit project to see the specific control's source code to take a deep understanding on using this control. Checking its source code, you will know how the control to work. This is a learning method that can help you improve your programming skills when developing UWP app.

Comment: Hi, I did create a new blank UWP project and tried to copy-paste the code there. Still unfortunately, only the DataGrid headers appear, there is no data inside it. I'm sure that I installed the correct NuGet package by following that instructions

Comment: @Sparker0i Please provide a [mcve]. You could upload it and post the link here.

Comment: Hi, I've uploaded my code to https://github.com/Sparker0i/Salary-Calculator

Comment: @Sparker0i See my [record video](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KnQQ9N1OAc5kkYX70?e=2qQupa). It did work for me. Why did you say there's no data inside it?

Comment: The same code worked? Strange, it does not work for me. What else could it depend on? I'm sure that I have the correct NuGet package installed. Is it because I did this in VS 2019 Community? But I don't think an IDE should be the cause of concern

Comment: @Sparker0i Yep. I did not do any changes for your project. I just open it and rebuild it to run. What's your OS build version? If possible, please try it on another machine.

Comment: Win 10 Pro 64 bit v1903, Build 18362. Ran the app with x64 target.

Comment: @Sparker0i You're using the windows insider preview version. I tested your code in 17763 OS, it does work. Please submit this issue in **Windows Feedback Hub** app.